Is there something wrong with this power-on latch circuit?
I am analyzing an electronic device that has an MCU and the following characteristics:

it is powered from a 3.7 V Li-ion battery
it has an on/off button that needs to be pressed 1 second to power-on the device
it can be powered from +5 V USB

Here is the schematics of the power-on latch circuit of the button:


+BATT is the battery voltage
+5V is the USB voltage
VCC is the power supply of the rest of the circuit
BUTTON_STATE is normally high. When the user presses the button, it goes low. The MCU detects it, and if it is a long-press, it sets and maintains CMD_ON_OFF high, which makes Q6 passing, thus powering the rest of the circuit.

I have a situation where some devices (maybe 1 % of them) switches on by themselves, without any press on the button (and without USB powering as well).
Is there something wrong with this circuit that could explain this behavior?
Thanks.

Q8 and Q12 have base resistors ? I guess the rest of the circuit which is supplied by Vcc is, if USB power is available, powered by the USB instead of the battery. If so, is there some interconnection between Vcc and 5v which is not shown on schematic ?

Q8 and Q12 do not have base resistors. Are they necessary ? You mean a series resistor or a parallel resistor to ground ? I am more used to deal with MOSFET than bipolar transistors.
If USB is available, then it switches Q8, so +BATT = VCC and the circuit is powered, but there is no direct connection between VCC and USB. USB goes into a charger that handle the battery charging.

Q8 and Q12 each require a current limiting resistor (say 1k) in series with the base. If Q8 base is powered by 5v (USB) as shown it appears that it will prevent the MCU from releasing the latch. Is this what you observe/want ? I think you have to show more of the schematic where USB (5v) "meets" Vcc or are you saying these are directly connected to each other? Also be aware that any voltage applied at Vcc (say derived from USB) will back feed the battery through the mosfet body diode. This may not be desirable.

@6v6gt those transistors have internal resistors. See the notes by them in the schematic, also check the part numbers.

@6v6gy : In my case where the device switches on by itself, the USB is not plugged into the device, so Q8 is opened.
USB and VCC are never connected

@Rohat Kılıç OK. Thanks. I hadn't seen that before. A built in current limiting resistor on the base and a base pull down resistor : https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PDTD113ZT.pdf

@uz3il OK. Sorry about the base resistor diversion. So the MCU is connected between Vcc and the common ground GND shared with the rest of the circuit. There is no supply to +5v yet sometimes (or with some examples of this circuit) it can spuriously switch itself on. Is that correct ?

That's entirely correct ! Which is why I thought there was something wrong with the latch circuit...

You've mentioned 1% of these devices behave incorrectly. So you have a large quantity of these ? What are the failure symptoms ? Does the MCU switch on then immediately off again because the latch is not sustained or does it stay continuously on ? Are bad devices always bad or also sometimes work correctly.
If there is only the battery and no +5v power source is involved, all I can imagine is that, in some devices either the mosfet is faulty (Source Drain leakage/short) or the 100k pullup resistor is faulty/bad solder joint or otherwise a short to ground somewhere in the mosfet gate circuit.

When the device switches on, it stays on for several minutes. Then after a while it stops. Then after a while it switches on again... It's a bit random. And it concerns only a small amount of devices (yes I have lots of them)
OK so your opinion is that it has more to do with faulty component than a faulty design. Thanks !

The circuit that you've shown with the additional information that the 5v is not used here seems OK. One thing to try, but only as a test, is to replace the 100k gate pullup resistor with something stronger (say 10k) to see if the problem goes away. This could indicate a bad mosfet. I had, incidentally, exactly this today with a PMOS (AO3401 from a Chinese retailer) in a high side switch which started half switching on without input.

How is the MCU powered?

It is powered from VCC

You might want to refresh your knowledge how this site works by re-taking the [tour]. To add new information, please [edit] your question. This is not a forum. Information down here in the comments will not be read.
